# Send Email As distribution group address

Tags: exchange-2013

I need to send a Mail from one of our **distribution group**.
I setup the permissions for my personal account, so I can send  "as" and send in the name of that mail account. 
Theres also an SMTP address configured for it. But when I actually try and send the message in Outlook, im getting a error back:
Recipient not available, error code [0x80070005-00000000-00000000]

I tried it with internal and external addresses, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can grant the send-as permission for the mail user with cmdlet, but we cannot login his internal mailboxes, because it isn’t enabled. I also test with the external mailbox, since there is no federation ship, I got the error, [0x80070005-0x000004dc-0x00000524].

So we could know, we cannot use mail user to send as a DL in Exchange organization, even though the permission can be added successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Run the cmdlet to add the permission:

Add-AdPermission -Identity Group -User  -ExtendedRights "Send As"

Test to send as the group in OWA, if it works in OWA, please download new OAB or recreate Outlook profile.

Comment: It says the flag was already set. And I still get the same result.

Comment: Did you test on OWA?Did it work?

Comment: The group doesnt show up in the "from" drop down list in OWA.

Comment: Is it mail user or mail contact? Based on my knowledge, we cannot grant permission for mail contact.

Comment: I'm a full mail user. Granting the permission worked too, both in the GUI and the cmdlet. Weird